# Android library calls setContentView using its own resource, but fails with "unable to resolve static field"

Tags: android, android-layout, resources

I've written + imported my own library that includes an OAuth login feature.  It needs to call **"setContentView(R.layout.authorize)"** on its own layout resource, **authorize.xml** which is defined in the library's *res/layout* folder.  If I run the library as a regular project (using a test Activity), everything works fine.  However, if I use the library in another project, I get the following error, indicating my **authorize.xml** layout cannot be found.

```
05-17 16:56:10.436: W/dalvikvm(212): VFY: unable to resolve static field 29 (twitter_authorize_webview) in Lcom/skworks/twitter/R$layout;
05-17 16:56:10.436: W/dalvikvm(212): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x60 at 0x0003
05-17 16:56:10.436: W/dalvikvm(212): VFY:  rejected Lcom/skworks/twitter/AuthorizeActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
05-17 16:56:10.436: W/dalvikvm(212): Verifier rejected class Lcom/skworks/twitter/AuthorizeActivity;
05-17 16:56:10.436: W/dalvikvm(212): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/skworks/twitter/AuthorizeActivity;)
```

Here is the code in my main activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AuthorizeActivity.class);
i.putExtra("URL", mRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
this.startActivityForResult(i, TWITTER_AUTH);
```

And obviously this is in *onCreate* of my AuthorizeActivity class, found in the library.

```
setContentView(R.layout.authorize);
```

I'm sure something is not setup correctly to expose resources defined in my library.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check the build settings for your library. It could be that it is not packaging up the layout file into your jar/apk. It could also be that the project using the library is not bundling the files into the deliverable apk. That's where I would start looking.

Comment: That's exactly it - I had to export the generated resource file.  Using Eclipse I've done it by going to my Gen folder, right click, and export R.java to a new jar file.  Is there any way to include my resources with my generated classes?  ie - just have one jar file?  I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: To be honest I have never made a library. I just know how they work and guessed what your problem was. You would have to consult the eclipse/java world for an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Check imports, that you havnt imported the android.R.
Else as mtmurdock said, check that your project is being build, try clean it.
You might have an xml error.